# How to deal with Android memory management and onTrimMemory callback?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-memory

I have a custom Application class with a lot of instance attributes and the activities relies on this attributes. Sometimes when the activity is in background and i open the app, some null pointer exceptions happens. I know that the cause of this problem is that Android is killing the app. When i open the app, the current activity is created again, but now the Application attributes is null.

I have two options of how to solve this issue. Both solutions require the onTrimMemory method to clear the Application cache when the level is TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE or above.

1º - When the cache is cleared and the app is opened, the current activity is finished if a required Application attribute is null. Only the main activity will load the Application attributes again. This require less work because the most refactor will happen in the main activity.

2º - Refactor all activities to load all required data from the backend everytime that an Application attribute is null. Here i have a lot of work because all activities must to be independent and must to know how to load his own data.

What is the best way to deal with this Android behavior? How to you solve this issue? What i need to do to prevent this null pointers when the cache data are cleared from the custom Application class?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about your Data Repository Architecture there but you should follow these rules:

1. TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND - try to remove all the roughly needed resources, things that you know you will not need to re - start your activity
2. TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE - you can clear also some Activity needed resources that could be easily loaded by a Loader or some AsyncTask
3. TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE - you may think to clear almost everything inside your Application class and only keep minimal - required data for your Application to launch and properly restore the activity state.

Except for those 3 above I also recommend you to use TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN which means that you Activity is no longer visible and you can release large UI related resources, especially Bitmaps :) cached inside your activity.

Comment: I decided to use TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE, but i need more details of how about the activities should behave when the cache is cleared. The AsyncTask for example should be placed in onResume? For now i'm finishing the activities when attributes on the cache is not found.

Comment: You should not do that, you should not finish your activities manually only if it is a wanted behavior according with you design/functionality flow. For activities you should most of the time use AsyncLoaders to load your needed resources, they already handle the Cache for you and when the Activity is destroyed they will be cleared.

Comment: The biggest problem I'm having now is an activity with four fragments (tabLayout). They was already rendered previously. When this activity is resumed I need to refresh all views  with actual data. The onResume of the activity is called first and loads basic data from the backend. The fragments onResume runs in parallel because the activity onResume load things asynchronously. The fragments load data from backend too. This is causing a strange behavior in the recyclerviews and other components because it must run in order like the first time they are loaded.

Comment: I would add/create an AsyncLoader for each fragment and handle the data loading individually on each of them and not into the activity. This is the best pretty straight - forward solution for what you have there: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Comment: Or if you want the new MVP way, you can use RxJava  for each of your Presenters to fetch the data or if you do not want to use RxJava you can start building your Local Central Repository Class and use EventBus instead to dispatch your DataEvents back to your presenters.